# How do I add Ubuntu option on the Windows Boot Manager menu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, windows-7, wubi

Currently i am on dual boot system.After repair **Window7**,windows boot manager can not show **Ubuntu** option on startup.when computer start,system directly opens Window7.my Window7 on **C:** and Ubuntu on **D:**.

Comment: Incomplete information: provide details of pc model ubuntu version default boot mode...

Comment: There is nothing like Ubuntu is on D u didnt install it correctly on dual boot mode

Comment: Windows bootloader will not show Ubuntu, it works for Windows only.

Comment: Yes i know but my problem is window boot manager can not show ubuntu option after i repaired window7

Comment: How can i create link between ubuntu to window boot manager so ubuntu can start.

Comment: If your tag 13.04 is correct, your question is off-topic. see [13.04 info](http://askubuntu.com/tags/13.04/info)

Comment: Ok sorry about tag..

Comment: If your tag 13.04 is wrong..If you want to restore the Wubi Ubuntu entry, see [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20340/how-to-restore-the-wubi-ubuntu-bootloader/)

Comment: @ngng thanks and do not consider tag.it link can apply to any wubi version.i solved out my problem with help of this link on both 13.04 and 16.04

Comment: @denny The problem of 13.04 is not that the linked how-to doesn't work. But there are general problems if your version is EOL. see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReleaseEndOfLife). So If we help you to run a EOL version, sometimes we also help you to get these problems.

Comment: @ngng plz read your comment.u said "if your tag 13.04 is wrong".

Comment: @denny Sorry, I misunderstood your comment "on both 13.04 and 16.04". The correct version is only 16.04.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use the Boot-Repair tool. To do this

1. Download Boot-Repair from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/).
2. Burn it on a USB stick or on a DVD. (Don't burn it on a CD/DVD if you have Windows 8)
3. Boot your computer with the disk.
4. Choose language and connect to internet if possible.
5. Try "Recommended Repair"
6. Reboot.

More throughout tutorial can be found [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: ohk thanx but i like to solve with bcdedit or another windows tools.

Comment: You can try Windows Boot Repair but you'll need a bootable Windows 7 Disk.

Comment: Windows boot manager doesn't show option for ubuntu

Comment: When u installed Ubuntu... windows boot manager was overwritten by grub. Above method will repair grub and will show options to choose between Ubuntu and windows

Comment: @Mustafa Yılmaz  i have a bootable usb.i tried with **bootrec /fixmbr**  and **bootrec /fixboot** but problem can not be solve

Comment: @sardapv its problem after windows repair

Comment: Thats what i m saying..u will have to go by above method shown by mustafa ...to install grub...u can not load ubuntu option in windows boot manager

Comment: @sardapv window 7 and ubuntu installed properly year ago but problem in window 7 i solved it but another problem create with ubuntu.i explained above.

Comment: What repair did u do

Comment: First read about what is windows boot manager and grub..what happens when u bring back windows boot loader then ubuntu can not boot...u need to install grub to run both...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45751/discussion-between-denny-and-sardapv).

Comment: Sry m not able to access chat page..yes u can change boot order if it is still theere in bios menu... select Ubuntu

Comment: If UEFI-install, look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/696838/installed-updated-windows-8-uefi-after-ubuntu-restore-grub). If legacy-install, Grub is overwritten by Windows-boot-loader, use boot-repair to reinstall Grub in MBR is easiest way to do...